# disable initial sorting in jquery data table and enable reordering

Tags: jquery, datatables

```
$('#selectedQuestionGrid').DataTable({
        rowReorder: {
            selector: 'tr'
        },          
        "columns": [
           {"visible": false,"orderable": false,"bSortable": false},    
           {"visible": false,"orderable": false,"bSortable": false},    
            {"orderable": false,"bSortable": false},    
            {"orderable": false,"bSortable": false}     

        ],
      aaSorting : []
    });
```

I need to disable initial sorting because I need to display whatever the order coming from DB but then I need give reordering feature. If I disable initial sorting by using `aaSorting: []`, reordering is not working!

Comment: What do you want as output ramya Lowda?

Comment: @Ramya, try "ordering": false.

Comment: $('#example').dataTable( {
  "ordering": false
} );

Comment: Tried,didnt Work..

Comment: @AKA need to disable initial sorting ,but allow user to do manual reordering  on datatable

Comment: did you try this: $('#example').dataTable( { "order": [] } )

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#selectedQuestionGrid').dataTable( {
   "order": []
} );
```

No ordering applied by DataTables during initialisation. The rows are shown in the order they are read by DataTables (i.e. the original order from the DOM if DOM sourced, or the array of data if Ajax / data sourced):

https://datatables.net/reference/option/order

Comment: If I disable this way (using above ) or using aaSorting: [] ,Reordering is not working,Reordering is what I need to do.